# Generating index in pdf using table of content available in pdf

Tags: ghostscript, pdftk

I have a pdf file basically RTC datasheet,
It is not allowing to jump to page using table of content and it doesn't have index or bookmark on the left side panel.
http://www.horustech.com.tw/WebMaster/FileData/Epson/RX8900SA(SA;CE).pdf

Now my question is it possible to update index/bookmark in this pdf using ghostscript or pdftk command ?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a *new** PDF file, and you could add to that a new /Outlines tree (which I believe is called Bookmarks by Acrobat), but you would have to do it by creating a sequence of PostScript pdfmark operations. You would have to build those yourself, there's no way to do it automatically.

You could also (more difficult) /Link annotations to the table of contents so that it could jump to the relevant page/area. Again with Ghostscript you would have to do this by manually creating pdfmark operations.

Again, none of this can be done automatically, creating the pdfmarks would have to be done manually, especially the hyperlinks in the table of contents, those are almost certainly better handled using an interactive program, if you wanted to do that.

I'm reasonably sure you could do this with pdftk too, but again I think you would have to add the Outlines or Links manually.

Comment: I was thinking that somehow if creation of pdfmark is possible to automate then it would be easy :(. Thank you for reply.

Comment: Certainly you could automate the creation of pdfmarks, I don't see how you are going to automate extracting the data from the PDF file in order to create the pdfmarks. For example, the first page in a PDF file may not be page 1, so if your table of contents has an entry which points to page 1, not only will you have to extract the index text from the PDF file (already a non-trivial and not 100% guaranteed problem) you will also have to identify which page in the PDF file is page 1.